# I got 2 versions of jQuery, why doesn't noConflict() allow me to use the proper one?

Tags: jquery

I have a boolmarklet loading this script, which loads jQuery. I try to avoid conflicting with any already loaded jQuery on the site.

When I do this:

```
/* Loading jquery and making sure we don't enter in conflict with
another js lib or another jquery */
var oldJquery;

if (typeof jQuery !== "undefined") { 
    log('jQuery is present. Setting noConflict() on', jQuery().jquery)
    oldJquery = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
} else {
    oldJquery= false;
}

log('Starting to load jQuery')
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js?' + (new Date().getTime());
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    log('jQuery is loaded. Starting BM with', $().jquery)
    bookmarklet(jQuery.noConflict(true))
    if (oldJquery){
        log('Restore old jQuery reference')
        jQuery = oldJquery;
        $ = jQuery;
    }
    }, 4000)

};
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange
head.appendChild(script);
```

I end up with this ouput:

```
############# RESTART #############

jQuery is present. Setting noConflict() on1.4.4
Starting to load jQuery
jQuery is loaded. Starting BM with 1.4.4
Scratchpad (ligne 312)
BM is started with jquery version 1.4.4
Scratchpad (ligne 27)
Display alert: Please wait...
Load view jQuery viewport plugin and wait for DOM ready
Restore old jQuery reference
```

Why on earth don't have I 1.8.2 as a jquery version in "BM is started with jquery version"  ?

I tried various combinaision of `($|jQuery).noConflict([true])` without success. Emptying the cache doesn't seem enought, and I can't possibly ask an end user to do it anyway.

Comment: Not that this is necessarily the problem, but the scope of `oldJquery` is limited to the `if` and `else` statements, but it is being used in your `onreadystatechange` event.

Comment: don't you think it's a compiling time logic mistake. like it's reading the 1.4.4 before adding the new one. just try getting the BM again after appending the script. what would the result be??

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Executing it after appending the script doesn't allow time for the script to be fetched and interpreted.

Comment: Is it possible that `onreadystatechange` is being called before the script has been fully executed?  Try appending a `log()` to the end of the jquery-1.8.3.min.js file just to ensure that it actually did get parsed before the readystate changed.

Comment: What if I do a e $document.ready(). Would it allow it to wait for the parsing to be complete ?

Comment: Ok, I added a 4 seconds timeout in the onreadystatechange callback and moved oldJquery on the upper scope. I still got the same results. I'll changed my code so that reflect this information.

Comment: Wait, my change may have no effet, because I'm creating the closure at a time where jQuery is still the old one, don't I ? But noConflict(true) is supposd to get rid of all references. I could manually void the variables myself and see.

Comment: What conditions are you testing this under? I created a test case on jsFiddle and your code seems to be working properly. I'm using Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/tC8kB/

Comment: Ok, I tried with a 10 seconds timeout and a `void jQuery` in the first `if` clause with no results.

Comment: I'm using the latest firefox on Ubuntu, and execute that in the javascript scratchpad. I will try a different environnement, see if it's the problem.

Comment: I just tried by loading the script from a bookmkarlet directly, and it seems to work. Maybe using the firefox scratch pad has some kind of issues. Thanks for helping guys.